# How to connect Microsoft SQL Database with Active Directory Password Authentication (AD Login)

Tags: sql-server

I have web application and I wanted to use **Active Directory Password Authentication** for Database login.

I already setup user login for Active Directory, but it show the error like below.

[image]

Help me! please...

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Could you possibly describe how you are trying to connect to your SQL Server instance (Connection string, GUI settings, ....)? Is it a local instance? Is it a SQL Express Edition?

Comment: This is not an authentication error. Your connection information is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Is this an Azure SQL Database or a database on a SQL Server instance?

Active Directory Password Authentication is only available for connecting to Azure SQL Database, so it seems like you're connecting to a SQL Server instance which won't work.

Check out this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) for information on the various authentication methods in SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. If you're using an SQL Server instance then it sounds like what you're looking for is Windows Authentication.

Your web application will need to use integrated Windows authentication as well, here is a link to an older [article](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c7725/How-to-Use-Windows-Authentication-to-Access-SQL-Server-Through-a-ASPNET-Web-Application.htm) that explains how to do this.

Comment: I'm not using Azure SQL DB, it is just a database on a SQL Server instance. Do you mean I can't use AD Login if it's not Azure SQL Database? is there another way to connect SQL server db with AD login? Thanks for your answer , bro..

Comment: @SirJax - You can use Windows Authentication which checks the logged in user against AD using NTLM or Kerberos, so you don't pass a username and password to SQL. Check the second link in my answer for information on using Windows Authentication in SQL using a web application. It is a common scenario and not too difficult to implement. The key to understand is you don't send the username and password to SQL Server, you validate their account via the web application then pass through that authentication to SQL Server.